# Во что обернуть ListBoxItem, чтобы он не считался элементом?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, события, wpf-commands

Делаю проект на MVVM и не хотелось бы прибегать к именам для обработки событий типа дабл клика. Но возникла проблема с `ListBoxItem`, так как при его использовании появляется фантомный элемент и я не могу забиндить `ItemSource` `ListBox`'a. Ошибка:

> System.InvalidOperationException: "Перед использованием свойства
> ItemsSource семейство Items должно быть пустым."

```
                 <ListBox
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Margin="0,0,10,0"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding UserList}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedUser}">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Border VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="40" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Margin="10,5,10,5"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        Text="{Binding UserId}" />

                                    <TextBlock
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Margin="10,5,10,5"
                                        FontSize="15"
                                        Text="{Binding Login}" />
                                </Grid>
                            </Border>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <!--во что обернуть-->
                    <ListBoxItem>
                        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Test}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    </ListBoxItem>
                </ListBox>
```

Comment: Зачем вам этот `ListBoxItem`? Какую задачу вы конкретно решаете?

Comment: Хотелось чтобы по даблклику по айтему выполнялась команда.

Comment: По определенному или по всем? Если по всем, то почему ваша команда идет отдельным объектом?

Comment: Допустим мне нужно чтобы переходило на view книги по котороый был сделан даблклик, но я не знаю как это сделать с помощью команды.

Comment: Вы мне не отвечаете на поставленный вопрос, да и при чем тут книги, где связь?  Я например вижу `UserList`, а вы говорите про книгу... Что конкретно вам надо? Вот у вас есть список, вы сейчас добавили в него допустим `ListBoxItem`, предположим, что нету ошибки, этот `ListBoxItem` с кликом отобразился в самом конце, вы это поведение хотите? Или хотите, чтобы при клике **на каждый** элемент списка происходила команда? Если второе, то почему эта команда не внутри `ItemTemplate`, которым вы переопределяете вид **каждого** объекта `ListBox`, а отдельным, не связанным объектом?

Comment: Сейчас делаю тоже самое со списком книг и немного перепутал. И если добавлять в xaml `ListBoxItem`, то ошибка будет в любом случае.

Comment: Если вам нужно, чтоб только некоторые объекты имели двойной клик (как сейчас допустим, в конце списка), то делайте интерфейс или абстрактный класс, от которого будете наследовать объекты, далее `UserList` делайте как `ObservableCollection<ISomeInterface> UserList { get; }` и на основе типа, делайте нужный вид, в XAML за это отвечает `DataTemplate`, которому вы можете указать тип, для которого будет применен вид внутри.